# Getting [object] when passing parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that takes three arguments.

```
initializeDateDropdown("year", "month", "day");

    function initializeDateDropdown(year1,month1,day1) {
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        $("#"+year1).append(function () {
            var yearList = '';
            for (var i = 1951; i <= currentYear; i++) {
                yearList += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
            }
            return yearList;
        }).val(currentYear)
      .add($('#'+month1).val(new Date().getMonth()))
      .bind('change', showDays);

        showDays(year1, month1, day1);

        $('#'+day1).val(new Date().getDate());


    }
```

In the definition of the `showDays()` method, when I try to display the year1, I keep getting `[object] [object]` and month1 and day1 as `undefined`.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code?

Below is the showDays method defination.

```
function showDays(year, month, day) {
        alert(year);
        var days = new Date($("#" + year).val(), parseInt($('#' + month).val(), 10) + 1, 0).getDate();

        var prevSelectedDate = $('#' + day).val();
        $('#' + day).empty();
        for (var i = 1; i <= parseInt(days, 10) ; i++) {
            $('#' + day).append($('<option />', { text: i, value: i }));
        }

        $('#' + day).val(prevSelectedDate);
    }
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Your trying to use that function as an event handler. When called in that case, it'll be passed an event object.

Comment: @PM : First initializeDateDropdown will be called then showDays will be called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `.bind('change', showDays)`, this is the equivalent:

```
.bind('change', showDays(event));
```

Where `event` is the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

You'll need to change that part of the function to:

```
.bind('change', function(){
    showDays(year1, month1, day1);
});
```

Since you need to pass parameters to the function (`year1`, `month1`, `day1`), you need to wrap it in an anonymous callback function.

On a secondary note, [`.bind` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
.on('change', function(){
    showDays(year1, month1, day1);
});
```